Adjustable frequency, voltage wave transformer circuit

I am kinda building a signal generator with the help of a 555 timer IC. The purpose of this circuit is to produce square, sinusoidal, and triangular waves with an adjustable voltage range of 0-1V and a frequency range of 1-10 kHz. The problem I am facing is with the filtering stage using op-amps. I cannot achieve a smooth output wave. Could there be an issue with the way I am implementing it? (I have added several potentiometers to adjust the frequency and amplitudes of the waves.)

This one is the one of the results which is works.

I am not familiar with this topology. I would like to learn more about it. Open to source recommendations.

Have you got simulation results? Are they different from prototype results?

I added a result. For your second question: There is no prototype, I just combined what i found in internet.

Using a filter to "convert" a triangle wave or square wave to something approximating a sine wave will work if the frequency is fixed. This is because a fixed filter can attenuate the harmonics present in a square or triangle wave. However, if the frequency can vary over a wide range, (such as a decade) you will not be able to filter the harmonics properly with a fixed filter. You sine wave will appear "distorted" at some (or all) frequencies.

@MathKeepsMeBusy  Is there a way which I can use for my problem? I would like to learn.

The 555 is not that great a choice if you want sine waves. Look into the 8038.

Thank you for your answer but I need to tranform waves outside of the IC.
